# how to get duration for remote sound in background using RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask, rx-java

I'm trying to get duration of remote sounds, I already have the method that rerun duration like this

```
  showProgressDialog()
  for (i in playList.indices) {
                    var duration = 0L
                    try {
                        val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
                        retriever.setDataSource(
                            playList[i].download_url.replace(" ".toRegex(), "%20"),
                            HashMap<String, String>()
                        )
                        val timeInmillisec =
                            retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION)
                                .toLong()
                        duration = timeInmillisec / 1000
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                        duration = 0
                    }
                    playList[i].audioLength = duration.toString()
                }
```

I have a PlayList and I need to update it, it takes some time, so, I want to update it in background task and show progress dialog to user until it updated, how to do it using RxJava

Comment: please show your effort, what have you tried so far with rxjava? where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have an observable that you want to measure it's time taking.

You can do:

```java
observable.doOnSubscribe(new Consumer<Disposable>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Disposable disposable) throws Exception {
       // start your timer
    }
}).doOnTerminate(new Action() {
       @Override
       public void run() throws Exception {
           // stop and calculate the time
       }
})
```